# Using the or and not operators

Tags: python, operators

Just wonder if somebody can help me with this.  I need to check if members equal to 3 different strings.  I've tried use `or`, but without success. The code is:

```
list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

for member in list:
    if not member == "a" or not member == "b" or not  member == "c":
        print member
```

I need to print just `"d"`.  I just need to get `"d"`.

Comment: `I need to print just "d". I just need exclude "d"` which is it: print just d or exclude just d?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need a single `in` test:

```
for member in list:
    if member not in ('a', 'b', 'c'):
        print member
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In my case, in original code I don't know the name of that member. I need to get that name. I know only  'a', 'b', 'c' names.

Comment: @iRex Yes, and this solution gets you what you want if you only know 'a', 'b', and 'c'.

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I'm very newbie in programing and. That works fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just one question more. Why tuple and not a list?

Comment: @iRex It wouldn't matter much in this case, but creation of tuple is quite faster than a list for the same number of elements. But you can even use a list, that wouldn't make any significant difference if any in performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to work, you just need to replace the 'or's with 'and's. Still, Rohit Jain's answer is a better way to express the same thing.

Comment: Thanks that helped. In original code I do know only  'a', 'b', 'c'  names. The goal is to get name of fourth member - 'd'. My fault, I did not mentioned it in first post. Anyway, thank you very much. Replacing with 'and' helped.